# iOS Development Security advice

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, security

I want to create a new iOS app.
and for this app I have some security questions

Example
The first start the user log in with username and password. When the log in is correct  The user receive a api code. Just This code Will be stored in the app
So every time they use a make a request to the side like calling for the use a list I don't send the username and password I will send the api code for authentication.

Like this

```
https://example.com/api/{APICODE}/getUserList
```

The answer will be json

So my Questions are
- how to securely store the api code in the app
- is there a better way to make the requests
- I will store the requested data in the app, what is the best way, SQLite or plain files with json
The reason is That the app works without Internet

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Save secured data in the Keychain. For other you may use UserDefaults, files, SQLite DBs, CoreData